# array copy reversal in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, copy, reverse

Is there a way to copy an array to another way in reverse order by using a while loop in c++??
I'm pretty sure I know how to do one with a for loop, but I'm curious if anyone knows of a way by using a while loop

Answer (score 9):

Why not something like this?

```
#include <algorithm>

int src[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int dst[5];

std::reverse_copy(src, src+5, dst);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int anArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int reverseArray[5];
int count = 4;
int place = 0;
while(place < 5) {
  reverseArray[place] = anArray[count];
  count--;
  place++;
}
```

Comment: -1 If the termination condition is `(place >= 0)` and you only increment `place` how will your loop ever exit.

Comment: Fixed, made some changes and forgot to change that.

Comment: OK, removing the -1 since you edited it. Beware, others may not be so kind ;-)

Comment: @Jordonias: There are still two more to go.

Comment: @cpx: I see the possibility of an unnecessary &&. If there is anything else I am missing it.

Comment: @Jordonias: Just a pair of brackets [] beside the array name, I removed my downvote.

Comment: @cpx -- clearly I need to upgrade my eyeball compiler to the version you are using!

Answer (score 1):

As you said that you have done using `for` loop, you can follow following steps to convert it to `while` loop.

```
for(int i = sizeof(arr) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  // your logic
}
```

now convert it to,

```
int i = sizeof(arr);
for(; i >= 0; )
{
  // your logic
  i--;
}
```

simply replace `for` with `while` and remove `;` within the braces.

```
int i = sizeof(arr);
while(i >= 0)
{
  // your logic
  i--;
}
```

Comment: sizeof(arr) only returns the number of elements in the array if the elements are 1 byte long, otherwise, nice explanation.

Comment: ... and if arr is really an array and not a pointer or any kind of container.

Comment: @all, agree with the comments, but that's just a pseudo code to explain the conversion of the loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::reverse` for reversing the same array and `std::reverse_copy` for reversing to another output array as:

```
int main() {
        int a[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        const int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
        int b[size];

        //copying reverse to another array
        reverse_copy(a, a + size, b);
        cout << "b = {";
        copy(b, b + size, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
        cout << "}" << endl;

        //reverse the same array
        reverse(a, a + size);
        cout << "a = {";
        copy(a, a + size, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
        cout << "}" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
b = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, }
a = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, }
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/Fe5uj

Comment: never came across that ideone site before that's pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

There's been a few questions similar to this recently. I wonder if it is homework or an interview question somewhere. Here's one answer:

```
#define ELEMENT_COUNT(a) (sizeof((a))/sizeof((a)[0]))


int anArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int reverseArray[ELEMENT_COUNT(anArray)];
int n = ELEMENT_COUNT(anArray);
int i = 0;
while(n--)
    reverseArray[i++] = anArray[n];
```

I think it might be probing to see if you understand when expression like i++ and n-- are evaluated.